# adding internal workbook to PP chart

Tags: c#, excel, powerpoint, openxml

I would like to attache workbook created in memorystream to powerpoint chart. I have created that workbook (I am not sure now if in 100% properly), and I need to somehow attach it to chart and whole PP package.

```
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memoryStream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
        WorkbookPart wbPart= spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
        // create the worksheet
        WorksheetPart wsPart= wbPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();

        wsPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
        Worksheet ws=wsPart.Worksheet;
        ChartSpace chartSpace=chartPart.ChartSpace;
        List<StringReference> dataReferences = chartSpace.Descendants<StringReference>().ToList();
        if (dataReferences!=null)
        {
            Support.SupOpenXML.FillWorksheetWithChartData(wsPart.Worksheet, dataReferences);
        }

        ws.Save();
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        var sr = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
        string myStr = sr.ReadToEnd();
        chartPart.AddEmbeddedPackagePart(myStr);
```

Last operation gives me an error, there are some weird values in myStr. What should I change in code to work? What relationships should I change in it to work?

Stream: `"PK\0\0\0\b\0*~hH\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0xl/workbook.xml ?\0(?\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0PK\n\0\0\0\0\0*~hH\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\v\0\0_rels/.rels ?\0(?\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0PK\0\0\0\b\0*~hH????\0\0\0\0a\0\0\0\0xl/worksheets/sheet.xml ?\0(?\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0PK\0\0\0\b\0*~hH\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels ?\0(?\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0PK-\0\0\0\0\b\0*~hH\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0xl/workbook.xmlPK-\0\n\0\0\0\0\0*~hH\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\v\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0I\0\0\0_rels/.relsPK-\0\0\0\0\b\0*~hH????\0\0\0\0a\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0?\0\0\0xl/worksheets/sheet.xmlPK-\0\0\0\0\b\0*~hH\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0?\0\0\0xl/_rels/workbook.xml.relsPK\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\03\0\0\0\0"`

Comment: Shouldn't AddEmbeddedPackagePart first be an object like in [this tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_jones/2009/06/30/embedding-an-open-xml-file-in-another-open-xml-file/), then you could call FeedData on it with a stream?

Comment: I added it in the way as it is shown in this tutorial, but the embedded file is not shown as an excel file only as a "package.bin". I can unzip it, and it looks then properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used below code:

```
        List<ExternalRelationship> references = chartPart.ExternalRelationships.ToList();
        for (int i = chartPart.ExternalRelationships.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            ReferenceRelationship refer = chartPart.ExternalRelationships.ElementAt(i);
            chartPart.DeleteReferenceRelationship(refer);
        }
        chartPart.ChartSpace.RemoveAllChildren<ExternalData>();

        string relationID = "rId99999";
        EmbeddedPackagePart embeddedPackagePart1 = chartPart.AddNewPart<EmbeddedPackagePart>("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", relationID);
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        embeddedPackagePart1.FeedData(memoryStream);

        chartPart.CreateRelationshipToPart(embeddedPackagePart1, relationID);
        ExternalData externalData1 = new ExternalData() { Id = relationID };
        AutoUpdate autoUpdate1 = new AutoUpdate() { Val = false };
        externalData1.Append(autoUpdate1);
        chartPart.ChartSpace.Append(externalData1);
```

and it works now.